# Web-based file manager like File Thingie, but for S3?

Tags: file-sharing, amazon-s3, upload

At work, we use a little PHP script called [File Thingie](http://www.solitude.dk/filethingie/), which is a web-based file manager. Basically, an FTP replacement. It allows users to upload and download files, and most importantly, it has a simple authentication system that allows us to set basic access controls, so that clients login directly to their folder and don't get to root around the folders of other clients.

This works great. The thing is, I would love to have the files be uploaded to S3 instead of to the web server that's hosting this service.

I've seen some web-based S3 uploaders, but they seem to all be raw access, none of the app-level user authentication or access controls that make the File Thingie solution work for our use case.

Does anyone have any ideas of how I can replicate this setup with S3 storage instead of the web server's local storage?

Comment: If you or someone at your workplace are familiar with PHP you could modify the existing system to work with S3 via the AWS S3 API and IAM API (credentials).